# Read Resource into Byte Array in Qt (PyQt)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qwebview, pyqt5

How can I read a resource file (say like `assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf` or `assets/jquery/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js` which declared in a `myresources.qrc` file and using `pyrcc5.exe` compiled to a `myresources.py` module) in to a byte array, byte string (b'') and string ('')?

I have successfully managed to implement a custom schema handler (to handle requests like myscheme://controller/action/?param1=100 , deriving classes from `QNetworkAccessManager` and `QNetworkReply`). I needed this for if later this app should go online, I would experience a (more) seamless migration process.

Now I need to serve the files in the resources (html, css, js, images, fonts, ...) to `QWebView` in my custom scheme. I've tried `QFile` and it's `readAll` method.

This is my code:

```
f = QFile('qrc:///assets/jquery/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js')
f.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly | QIODevice.Unbuffered)

try:
    self.content = f.readAll()
finally:
    f.close()
```

It seems `f.readAll()` does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resource path is not correct, and the exception handler is redundant, because an error won't be raised if the open/read fails (that's not a bug or misfeature - Qt just works differently to Python).

Try something like this, instead:

```
    stream = QFile(':/assets/jquery/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js')
    if stream.open(QFile.ReadOnly):
        js = str(stream.readAll(), 'utf-8')
        stream.close()
    else:
        print(stream.errorString())
```