# PDF file in resources.py

Tags: python, pdf

I have included a pdf (help.pdf) in .qrc and converted it to .py using python. How can it be extracted and written to the local folder using python. Thank you

Comment: maybe try something similar to [Read Resource into Byte Array in Qt (PyQt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861534/read-resource-into-byte-array-in-qt-pyqt)